# Questionable duplicate index suggested by optimization

Tags: sql-server, index, index-tuning, azure-sql-database

Good day, I have the following sql server database table:
[image]

Please note the compound primary key.  This was done for 3 reasons:

- Prevent duplicate entries
- Improve query performance as all queries will have all of thoes 3 keys.
- We needed and index, and I did not want to introduce a random ID.

Please also note that this table was designed with its size in mind, This table is going to store millions and millions of rows of data.

OK now for my actual question. I am using azure sql server to host this db. and I have enabled automatic tuning. And strangely enough I see that it then went and created a new index. (see below)

[image]

Now In my mind this seems to be a duplicate index, as the same columns are being indexed.

So I now have two indexes on my table:

Original (My PK):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SensorDataRaw] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_SensorDataRaw] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DateTime] ASC,
    [SensorId] ASC,
    [Key] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

Newly Added (Auto Created by azure tuning):

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [nci_wi_SensorDataRaw_DC9789077DA75B4440AC8BFE3E2AA198] ON [dbo].[SensorDataRaw]
(
    [Key] ASC,
    [SensorId] ASC,
    [DateTime] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [Value]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

**Observations:**

- The order of the coloumns has been reversed in the new index.
- The new index is NOT unique
- the new index includes the value column.

Please note my knowledge on indexes is not advanced, hence me asking this.

So my question is:

1. Can someone explain why the newly added index is better than my intially created one.
2. How can I remove the two indexes and just create one that covers both cases. With this being such a massive database I cannot afford the space that both these indexes will take up.
3. Is the maybe a better design alternative?

Additional Info:

I'm assuming the type of queries becomes important here, So I have listed some examples.

All queries include `DateTime`, `SensorId`, and `Key`.

**Simple Queries:**

```
Select SensorId Where average value for key w is greater than x where time between (y,z)
```

**Graphing Data:**

```
SELECT AVG([Value]) AS 'AvgValue',    
    DATEADD( MINUTE, 
    (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '1990-01-01T00:00:00', [dbo].[SensorDataRaw].
[DateTime]) / @IntervalInMinutes) * @IntervalInMinutes,
        '1990-01-01T00:00:00'
    )      AS 'TimeGroup'
 FROM [dbo].[SensorDataRaw]
 where 
    [dbo].[SensorDataRaw].[SensorId] = @SensorId
    and [dbo].[SensorDataRaw].[Key] = @KeyValue
    and [dbo].[SensorDataRaw].[DateTime] Between @DateFrom and @DateTo
    and [dbo].[SensorDataRaw].[Value] IS NOT NULL  
  GROUP BY (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '1990-01-01T00:00:00', [dbo].[SensorDataRaw].
    [DateTime]) / @IntervalInMinutes)
```

Comment: Newly created index is not better than your own PK.Can't say why index is auto created and how to remove it.IMO create non clustered index on Value column and include DatetimeServer.Anyway DATEDIFF is not sargable.If you have created table keeping millions of rows in mind then why not store DateDiff logic in one column while populating.not much code is required for this.

Comment: The index it suggests *is* better than your original for the shown query. You want the columns matched by equality predicates first.

Comment: @MartinSmith, it is not clear to me,please explain.when I already have CI in those columns then why I will need NON CI in same columns. Or do you mean Create CI in some other column or do you mean CI is not require in this table at all.Also notice "Value" is use in where clause so you are suggesting it to include in NON CI.

Comment: @MartinSmith does the order of the columns matter, if all 3 columns are included in the query?

Comment: @KumarHarsh the `DateTimeServer` field is totally irrelevant to this question. Its a field that is there for debugging. It is not used in ANY queries.

Comment: Here is a good article explaining the implications of the `DateTime` RANGE search which effects the ordering of my columns in the index. http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/greater-less-between-tuning-sql-access-filter-predicates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The index suggested by the system is a much better fit for the query you have shown. You should aim to have columns with equality predicates as the leading columns.

Consider a phone book ordered by `lastname, firstname`. If your rquirement is to find all people with surnames between "Brown" and "Yates" and a first name of "John" then you need to read most of the phone book. If the phonebook was instead ordered by `firstname, lastname` you could easily find the "John" section and the first "Brown" in the section then all you need to do is read all the names until the `lastname` is after "Yates" or a new firstname is encountered.

It might not be the ideal index. Potentially you should just change the key columns in the clustered index to this order rather than creating a new one though. You need to evaluate this based on knowledge of your workload.

Comment: From what I have read, The order of the columns in an Index do not make a difference when you are providing ALL off the columns in your query. It would only make a difference, if say I only queried based on DateTime.

Comment: What you have read is incomplete then. Once you have read my answer you will have read something different. Column order is only irrelevant if all of them are in equality predicates.

Comment: This is probably for a different discussion.  But my thinking of the PK order.  Was to have it in the order of what filters it the most. For example there will be very few rows with the same datetime.  Simply filtering it by datetime will probably giver us 1 to 10 rows.  Where as the `sensorId` & `key` will be repeated many times. Key being the worst?  Filtering by key will result in millions of rows?

Comment: The query you have shown isn't searching for exact datetimes. It is searching for a range. And it needs to read all the irrelevant rows for other sensors and keys in that range. An index ordered by `[Key] ,[SensorId] ,  [DateTime]` can be efficiently navigated to the start of the exact range needed by the query and read exactly the needed rows.

Comment: Bam, That makes so much sense. I didn't think of the implications of the time range. And all those queries will have a range, Searching a specific timestamp will literally NEVER happen.  So I would think the following order would be best.  `(SensorId, Key, DateTime)` - Reason being SensorId is a bigint, which is smaller than Key `varchar(20)`, It will also filter to less rows than just key.

Comment: >>>Potentially you should just change the key columns in the clustered index to this order rather than creating a new one though<<< I  think it's not a good choice. From column names I suppose it's a log of some Sensors where every minute or any other time interval some parameteres are logged. So by having date column as the first we always write to the end of clustered table, and his query is typical for quering for some period for some sensorId and some parameter. It will be consecutive range in a table and clustered index will not be fragmented by INSERTS

Comment: @sepupic - the exact same hotspot and fragmentation will occur with a nonclustered index on those columns. The proposed NCI is basically a copy of the whole table (just missing one column) - if the CI is basically useless for other queries having a nicely unfragmented CI and the same amount of fragmentation on the NCI is not a benefit.

Comment: But nonclustered is an additional one that can be dropped if it will bring too slowlyness in INSERT process while we should preserve PK as it serves for uniqueness enforcement too

Comment: One would also eventually have to shard this table,  Which would then also want to spread insert values across the entire index, and not localize them all at the tail end.

Comment: @sepupic - yes they can preserve the PK but just re-order the columns - this doesn't affect the uniqueness aspect. But as I say the OP needs to evaluate this against their whole workload (including inserts)

Comment: Could I propose another option: Add a new column `RowId` either an auto-increment `BigInt` or a `Guid`. Make it the Clustered Index and PK.  And then simply add a `NCI` on the 3 columns (SensorId,Key,DateTime) including Value

Comment: It doesn't sound like that suggestion is really based on anything. The characteristics of a CI on a GUID and on an auto incrementing integer are entirely different. What would you be hoping to get out of this?

Comment: Having a separate insert point for every (key,sensor) won't lead to bad fragmentation, so long as each (key,sensor) pair has thousands of rows.  See, eg https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2012/06/25/good-page-splits-and-sequential-guid-key-generation/

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone explain why the newly added index is better than my
>   intially created one

Your index is `clustered` one, this means it includes **all the data** as the leaf level.

The index offered by server is **narrower** respect to clustered as it contains only `key fields` + `included field` on the leaf level.

Your query needs only `key fields` + `value` field so non clustered index offered you by server is sufficient, and it is chosen by server as the narrowest possible covering index.

> How can I remove the two indexes and just create one that covers both
>   cases.

You can remove non clustered index, your clustered is of course covering one, and if it has only 2 additional fields: datetime2(2) + decimal(19,4) respect to non clustered there will no huge overhead when using it instead of non clustered.

Comment: IMO,you need to revise your answer,in one place you suggest that system index is better and in last para you suggest to remove non cluster index.Also if you can reply to my query which i ask above.

Comment: @KumarHarsh If OP wants to keep both indexes why not? But if he asks "How can I remove the two indexes and just create one that covers both cases" the answer is to remove non clustered index

Comment: No main question is which one is better of two and if system index is not good then how to remove it ?

Comment: System index suits better for this query, where did you see "system index is not good"? But clustered index covers all the queries, not only one, besides, it's PK, so if one of them should be removed, it's non clustered that should be removed

Comment: I got your point.I suggested same in my comment above.Ok how come system index is good even for given query,see "value" is use in where clause and in system index value is use in covering index.Please explain.

Comment: >>>how come system index is good even for given query,see "value" is use in where clause<<< and what? it's used like [Value] IS NOT NULL. There is no difference if this condition is included in query or not, **value** is used in aggregation (AVG) and NULL values are just ignored. I suppose this condition was added only because they did not want to receive a warning "Null value is eliminated by an aggregate"

Comment: I miss this point AVG (Value).Last question with million of rows and suppose there is only one above query even then Clustered index won't perform better than system index which is non clustered index.

Comment: Myconcern with including value at the leaf level, is that you are then basically storing the entire table in the index. It will never actually do a physical read.  Which is fine for me. But then it seems waist-full storage. its gonna store everything in the table, and then store everything in the index.  Can I not have a table that is just an index?  Obviously including value in the index will help queries that want averages of values, or values bigger or smaller than.

Comment: >>>Myconcern with including value at the leaf level, is that you are then basically storing the entire table in the index<<< That is wrong. The suggested index has only one included column, so it will never store "entire table" unless you add **all the columns** as included.

Comment: >>>It will never actually do a physical read<<< What do you mean by saying this? If your table is read for the first time (after server restart for example) there will be physical reads, and this does not depend on included/non-included columns.

Answer (score 1):

The suggested index is narrower, that will make it more efficient when the query only deals with columns covered by that index.

The column order is also different which MAY make it more efficient for that particular query (I can't tell for sure without seeing an execution plan).  Column order DOES make a difference.

Which is better, the non-clustered index may be better for that particular query but wont cover everything.  Besides, the clustered index can't be removed and I don't see any problem with keeping both.

Try experimenting with the two, force the clustered index and check the execution plan and IO stats, then force the non-clustered and compare.

Comment: I like the idea to force the index on the query and then check the execution plans for it. With regards to keeping both. There will be a massive storage drawback as data will be duplicated in both indexes.

Comment: it'll depend on the size of the table, indexes are always going to be a pay off between overhead and performance benefit.  I'd test the two out, see how they perform and then decide if the non-clustered is worth having or not.

Comment: The design spec is that the table will grow to several Terra-bytes. In a case like this, I don't thing the fastest choice will always be the most practical choice. Generally with time series data, Read queries are a lot less frequent than inserts and deletes etc.  I think what would be key here, is more of a consistent response time with regards to select queries. With such a large table, one would probably have to add some sort of cache layer on the data in order to achieve blitz fast localized queries.